# html entities and angle brace issue

Tags: php, html-entities

So, I have this rel/URL I am trying to stuff into a variable so I can print it out elsewhere:

```
$relnext = "<link rel='next' 
                  href='javascript:".$content_pager->PagerName
                                    . "_form." 
                                    . $content_pager->PagerName 
                                    . "PagerPage.value=\"" 
                                    . $content_pager->Page+1 
                                    . "\"; " 
                                    . $content_pager->PagerName 
                                    . "DoSubmit();' />";
```

As it is, when I print it out, all I get is:

1"; MediaBoxContentDoSubmit();' />

After some research it 'appears' that I should use htmlentities, but:

```
echo htmlentities($relnext);
```

also just produces:

```
1"; MediaBoxContentDoSubmit();' />
```

Is there some other function that should be used here?

Thanks very much for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an operator precedence / associativity problem.  The `.` operator to the left of the `+` operator execute before the `+` operator, because they are all left-associative and have the same precedence.  You want the `+` operator (in `$content_pager->Page+1`) to execute first, then all the `.` operators.

As it is, you are adding a string to a number (1) with the `+` operator, in which case the string (everything before the `+`) will be taken as 0.  That is why the first character is a `1`, because it is the result of `"some string"+1`, which is interpreted as `0+1`.

So, your first snippet should be:

```
$relnext = "<link rel='next' href='javascript: " . $content_pager->PagerName . "_form." . $content_pager->PagerName . "PagerPage.value=\"" . ($content_pager->Page+1) . "\"; " . $content_pager->PagerName . "DoSubmit();' />";
```

Note that the `$content_pager->Page+1` part is now in parentheses.

More information:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question thoroughly!